# what is a more appealing way of doing this slide-out search bar

Tags: website-design, gui-design, design

I currently have a slide-out search bar within the navbar of my website. It works pretty well, however the colors and general *boxy layout* don't really match that well.

What is a better way of doing this to blend in more? At the moment, it feels extremely bleak.

This is a screenshot of the current search bar:

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks

Comment: It may look boxy because the other elements (in your screenshot) are rounded. Maybe consider rounding the ends of the search field and adding a margin around it to make it consistent with other elements on the navbar?

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions:

1. **Change search bar position:** When the search icon is clicked, a search bar appears below the navigation bar and the search icon changes to an *X* for closing the search. Another option is that clicking on the icon dims the whole website and displays a search bar in the middle of the screen. I would recommend one of these solutions.
2. **Change search bar style** When the search icon is clicked, it moves to the left to reveal a search bar on its right (shown on the image below). The bar together with the icon could also get a darkened background.

[image]

Comment: Thank for the answer, mate! :) I was originally going to make it so that the search icon floats to the left, however, I felt like it should be on the right, because after the user types in anything, I wanted it to be used as a submit button as well (if that makes sense).

Comment: Users already know that pressing enter will do the same thing. If you are really keen on using a submit button, it can appear on the right of the search field but I wouldn't do that.

Comment: I'm well aware that they know, however, I still want it there and on the right :) thanks for the answer though, dude! +1

Comment: No problem. Have a great day!